is it possible to feed multispectral images to VGG16?
Me and my thesis partner are developing a study based on image classification of 3 various diseases using multispectral images using VGG16. We also use U-Net for image segmentation before feeding it to VGG16. Since VGG16 accepts RGB inputs, we expect that there would be a way to feed multispectral images to it, such as 690 nm, 525 nm, and 320 nm. How can we feed 3 spectral images to VGG16? If here is a way, what are the preprocessing methods should we do? Should we also configure the VGG16 architecture?
(P.S. We are students new to CNNs)
